# Are there any macros that cannot be expressed as a function?

Tags: function, macros, lisp

Are there any **macros** that:

- **Cannot** be expressed as a equivalent **function**, or:
- Are **difficult** to express as a equivalent **function**, or:
- Are significantly worse in terms of **performance** than equivalent **function**?

Can you give an **example** of such a **macro** (and function)?

My question refers specifically to [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language))'s macros and functions, but you may treat this question more generally. I'm particularly interested in *recursive* macros.

---

**Edit:**

I should've been more specific. When I asked the above question, I kept in mind specific context of my *Lisp* project, which is kind of mathematical [symbolic programming](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SymbolicProgramming) calculator.

I was wondering if there is good reason to use macro for any of the mathematical operations, like:

- analytical [integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral),
- analytical [differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative),
- [polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial) operations,
- computing [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) for given function,
- computing [trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Implications),
- and so on...

For some reason I need to use a few **recursive macros** for this project. So, if I can reformulate my question:

> Can you give examples of smart use of [recursive] macros in a symbolic calculation?

Comment: "Can you give examples of smart use of [recursive] macros in a symbolic calculation?" is almost certainly off-topic, since it's pretty much a resource request ("Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow...").  That said, it *is* an interesting question, and I think that what you might want to look into here is [*compiler-macros*](http://goo.gl/FJ8aEQ). Common Lisp supports (normal) macros, and compiler macros. Compiler macros are probably more beneficial in certain types of symbolic computation.

Comment: As an aside, "moving-target" questions can be received somewhat poorly on Stack Overflow.  There are already two answers on this question, and by fundamentally changing the nature of the question, you've pretty much made them mostly irrelevant.  It might have been better to ask a new question rather than so radically change the existing one.

Comment: You don't *need* any macros for a symbolic programming calculator. Your question makes no sense. Your question would make sense, if you show your code where you use macros and we will tell you why that makes no sense. Since you changed your question already, I propose you delete this question and post a new one, with more specific content -> code.

Comment: I know, I know... You are right, that's my fault. It all began in head of one lecturer who made *recursive macros* as a stupid requirement. My question should be *not* considered as source code-related, because it all began from the lack of *concept* for suitable *recursive macros* in symbolic calculation project. On the other side, it is **not** completely dumb question. You could answer with more helpful answers, like: 'Try to `grep` [Maxima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima) looking for macros which turned out to be helpful in Maxima project' (`grep -iR "defmacro" maxima-5.37.3`).

Comment: All in all, you can vote to close this question.

Comment: Any macro that binds an identifier cannot be replaced with an equivalent function. The most obvious example is pattern matching.

Comment: @sk-logic you can't get the binding, no, but you could build the last of symbol to value mappings and query that at run time.  It'd be much slower obviously, but you could do the same thing, even if it'd be a bit more tedious.  Or you could do the matching and binding a bit more programmatically. There's still a sense in which the pattern matching is still just syntactic abbreviation. It's more like syntactic high fructose corn syrup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any **macros** that:
>
> - **Cannot** be expressed as a equivalent **function**, or:
> - Are **difficult** to express as a equivalent **function**, or:
> - Are significantly worse in terms of **performance** than equivalent **function**?

The answer is never quite this simple.  It's typically "yes and no".  As I see it, there are two big advantages of macros:  syntactic sugar delayed evaluation.  For instance, macros like **with-open-file**, which lets you write:

```
(with-open-file (var "some-filename")
  ; operations with var
  )
```

is pretty much just syntactic sugar for

```
(let ((x (open ...)))
  (unwind-protect 
    (funcall (lambda (var) 
               ; operations with var
               )
              x)
    ; cleanup forms
    ))
```

That's sort of a mix of delayed evaluation and syntactic sugar, depending on how you look at it.  It's delayed evaluation, in that all the operations with var are wrapped up into a lambda function.  It's also syntactic sugar, because you could obviously abstract the above into:

```
(defun call-with-open-file (open-args function)
  (let ((x (apply 'open open-args)))
    (unwind-protect (funcall function x)
      ; cleanup forms
      )))
```

and then **with-open-file** is just syntactic sugar:

```
(defmacro with-open-file ((var &rest open-args) &body body)
  `(call-with-open-file (list ,@open-args)
     (lambda (,var) ,@body)))
```

That's a typical case that exhibits both delayed evaluation (of the body forms) and syntactic sugar around a functional interface.  You can typically *always* do that.  E.g., with **if**, you could write a functional interface:

```
(defun %if (condition then &optional (else (constantly nil)))
  `(funcall (cond (condition then) (t else))))
```

Then **if** can be implemented as a macro:

```
(defmacro if (condition then &optional else)
  `(%if condition (lambda () ,then) (lambda () ,else)))
```

**if** and other conditional forms are a bit unique, in this sense, though, because the implementation ultimately has to provide you *some* conditional operation.  That operator typically isn't a *macro*, though, but a special form.

What about other special macros like **loop**, that define domain specific languages?  You can do those too, but you pretty much would just end up having the function accept the "body" of the macro version and interpret it at runtime.  E.g., you could do

```
(defun %loop (&rest loop-body)
  ; interpret body
  )
```

but that's obviously going to be a big performance hit.

So, I'd posit that there are no macros that don't have a semantic equivalent, but these will require somewhat different arguments.  Some of those semantically equivalent functions *will* be difficult to expression, and some of them (e.g., when passing anonymous functions around) will certainly have significantly worse performance.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is not well posed since it is based on the ambiguous use of the term “equivalent”. At a first sight, it seems that you intend “equivalent” as: “calculating the same value” (and this is confirmed by your third question about performance).

*But they are not equivalent at all*, because functions produce (or calculate) values, while macros produce (or calculate) programs! (and when you understand this, you will understand that a macro actually *is* a function, a function from s-expressions (the “quoted arguments”) to s-expressions).

So, I think that the answer to your questions should be given in these terms:

1) If you stretch the meaning of equivalence as “when the result of a macro, (i.e. a program), is further evaluated by the system”, than an answer like that of Joshua Taylor is to be taken into consideration;

2) If you are asking about macros and functions per se, they are *not equivalent* at all.

And concerning their use in the task you are addressing: macros can be really useful in defining particular control structures, or specialized ways of performing computation, like in DSL (Domain Specific Languages), but my advice is to use them *only* when you think that your problem could be solved in an easier way by adding to the usual tools (i.e. predefined functions, special forms and macros) new powerful tools, *and* when you have experience in writing complex macros (to practice this, see for instance the book of Paul Graham [On Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Lisp)).

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any macros that cannot be expressed as a function?

Yes; all macros in any expertly written Lisp program!

There are sometimes macros that *can* be replaced by functions, if you radically change or augment underlying language implementation.

For instance, a macro might be simulating something that otherwise requires continuations in a Lisp dialect that doesn't have them. Or it might be doing something that looks like non-strict evaluation, over a strict language. Something can can be done just with functions in a call-by-name language can be expressed with macros over pure call-by-value.

Macros go away when they are expanded; all that is left is special operators and functions. What functions can or cannot do depends on the available special operators. For instance without a operators to capture a continuation, a function cannot abandon its evaluation in such a way that it can be later restarted.

Therefore it is a false dichotomy to think about the power as being divided between macros and functions, while ignoring special operators.

A given problem can be solved by a combination of functions and special operators. If it requires certain special operators, then we cannot say that 
the problem is solved by functions alone.

Macros can be used in such a way that they hide the use of special operators. Macros which conceal the essential use of special operators cannot be rewritten as functions.

For instance, a macro that provides syntactic sugar over a `lambda` operator cannot be written as a function. The macro's essential functionality depends on the fact that it expands to a `lambda` operator which captures a closure in the original lexical environment where the macro call occurs.

When Lisp language designers extend a dialect with new core functionality, they do so by adding new special forms. Macros are added at the same time to make the forms easier to use. For instance, I recently added delimited continuations to a Lisp dialect. The underlying API is not the easiest thing to use for certain simple tasks, so I also provided macros which provide an easy-to-use "generator" abstraction. Needless to say, these generator macros cannot be implemented with functions. Not only that, those macros cannot be implemented *at all* without the delimited continuation support; all they do is write code that depends on using these new special forms, and those special forms are implemented by hacks deep the language core which do nasty things like copying sections of the run-time stack to the heap, and back to a different area of the stack.

Now in a purely interpretive Lisp that runs programs by evaluating raw source code, you can have a form of function which is as powerful as a macro (in fact, more so). This is a function which, when it is called at run-time, receives its argument expressions unevaluated, together with the run-time environment needed to evaluate them. Essentially, such a function, though written by the user, acts as an "interpreter plugin", called upon to interpret code in an arbitrary way. In historic Lisp terminology, this kind of function is called a "fexpr".

The relationship between macros and fexprs is that macros are to fexprs what compilers are to interpreters. If you have a dialect with fexprs, then there is no reason to use macros if the only requirement is to support some syntax with some semantics, without caring about performance. A macro may be able to do the same thing by compiling to a more efficient translation. Even though the dialect is purely interpretive, it's nevertheless faster to have the interpreter run some macro-generated code, than for the interpreter to interpret a function, which itself interprets code.

But, of course, though fexprs are functions, they are not ordinary functions; ordinary functions receive evaluated arguments and no environment. So that just changes the question to: *are there essential fexprs that cannot be replaced by ordinary functions?*

The answer is: yes, any fexprs in an expertly written program ...

Answer (score 0):

Any Lisp macro which does not evaluate ("twice", since it is a macro) its arguments cannot be expressed as a function, since function application is done on *evaluated* arguments. For example you could define a macro `my-if` which behaves exactly like `if` (and `if` *cannot* be a function)

C.Queinnec's book [Lisp In Small Pieces](https://pages.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html) explains that in great detail (and has several chapters about macros). I strongly recommend to read it (since answering your too broad question may require an entire book, not a paragraph).

If a macro expands one of its arguments several times, it might be slower than the equivalent function (because some sub-computations could be done twice if expanded twice).

<sup>(of course, the answer to all your questions can be *yes*; I leave up to you how to find some examples).</sup>

PS. BTW, this is even true in C....

Comment: The usual way to delay/force evaluation for my-if is to pass in thunks.

Comment: But then it is not an `if` any more

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch There's a sense in which it's not **if** anymore, but OP asked about macros that "Cannot be expressed as a equivalent function". A `(defun my-if (condition then-thunk else-thunk) ...)` makes `(if x y z)` *semantically* equivalent to `(my-if x (lambda () y) (lambda () z))`, in that the same forms are evaluated in the same conditions, and the same results are returned. (Of course, this is a strange case anyhow, since `if` (or `cond`) isn't a macro, but a special form;  somewhere the implementation has to provide a conditional operator that's not expanded into something else.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. They are as general as my question was. I edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: This is misleading. Some Lisp macros which don't evaluate some or all their arguments can still be trivially converted to simple function calls.  (Not exactly that syntax, of course, but close). For instance in a purely dynamically scoped Lisp dialect if we see a macro `(setq foo 42)` we can do that with a function `(set 'foo 42)`.  (The `q` in `setq` just tells us that it's an auto-quoting syntactic sugar for `set`).  Sure, the function cannot do it with the exact syntax `(whatever foo 42)`, but the matter of quoting is trivial. Now if we add lexical scope, the playing field changes.